# ctype: WindowsError: exception: access violation reading

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, windowserror

My environment: Windows Vista 64, Python3.1, Visual Studio 2008 sp1

Error Description:
I am trying to wrap a dll (eg. Lib.dll) using ctype, when proceeding to one of the function (eg. func()) in Lib.dll, an error occurred:

```
"WindowsError: exception: access violation reading"
```

I think the different between func() and previous functions of `Lib.dll` written in my '.py' file is that `func()` contains a DOUBLE type parameter, but I am sure that the parameter are passed correctly, since I have used `c_double()` to cast it. And it seems the error occurred when entering `func()`, since the first code `(printf()`) inside `func()` does not execute.

I also tried to run the same dll and its functions in C environment, it runs smoothly.

Further Information:

the lib.dll is compiled in MSVC (with extern "C"), and I am using CDLL for the calling type. The problem is actually happened on a function in another dll (lib2.dll). I use lib.dll only because the lib2.dll is written in C++ and I wrap the functions that I want in lib2. It looks like this:

```
///////////////////////////////////
// lib.cpp

lib2 l;

void func(char * c1, char * c2, double d) 
{
    printf("%s, %s, %f\n", c1, c2, d); // All the parameters are passed correctly
    l.func(c1, c2, d);                 // THIS IS where the error occurred
}
///////////////////////////////////
// lib2.cpp

void lib2::func(char * c1, char * c2, double d)
{
    printf();  // The error happened before this line being executed.
    ...
}
///////////////////////////////////
And python script looks like this:
// my.py

dll = cdll.LoadLibrary("lib.dll")

dll.some_func1(c_char_p('a'))
dll.some_func2(c_char_p('b'))

func(c_char_p('c1'), c_char_p('c2'), c_double(1.1))
////////////////////////////////////
```

it is also weird that lib2.dll cannot work when I use ctype to load it. It shows the function is not found. So I have to use lib.dll to call functions in lib2.dll.

Could anyone give me some hints? Thanks

Comment: put some code. `from ctypes import *` ...

Comment: Here's my guess as to why you can't call lib2.dll directly: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B

Comment: Thx for reply. I know the name will be mangled if there is no extern "C" or .def file, when compiling in MSVC, and func() would become something like '_func@YZ'. But even when I use those (.def and etc.), or use 'func = getattr(lib2, '_func@YZ')', it still not works.

Comment: BTW, I can load the lib2.dll without lib2.lib in another Project in MSVC, using loadlibrary(), and it works.

Comment: Try `dll.func.argtypes = [c_char_p,c_double]` before calling `func`. Also your `func` call has two `c_char_p`, but should only have one.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen, Thx for reply. I have already tried that, it still not works. I think the parameters are passed smoothly, since I can print them in func() of lib.dll correctly

Comment: About the # of parameters, in the real code, it actually has 3. I wrote it wrong here, and I have corrected it. Thx, but it's not the reason for this problem

Comment: Well, I guess I can load the lib2.dll using ctype directly, it seems I missed a dll file. But all the functions I want are defined as methods of a class (eg. Class A) in lib2.dll, which means I need to call its constructor and  create an object in order to call them. Is that possible when using ctype? I tried in python: a = A(); a.method(); not works. Anyway, it is not the main problem I want to solve now. I still have no idea about the "WindowsError" thing...

Comment: Have you tried using windll instead of cdll?

Comment: Ctypes is for C, it won't work with classes.  You'll need something like boost.Python, Cython, or SWIG for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ctypes` is for C, but you can write a wrapper to expose a C++ class.  Since you mentioned you use Python 3.1, I also noted you have `c_char_p('c1')` where `'c1'` is a Unicode string.  Since the example provided is not a complete example that can be used as is to reproduce the problem, it's difficult to tell what problem you are having.

Below is a complete, working example.  You can build it from a Visual Studio command prompt by running "nmake".

#### lib1.cpp

This wrapper "flattens" the C++ object into a C API.

```
#include "lib2.h"
extern "C" {
__declspec(dllexport) lib2* lib2_new() { return new lib2; }
__declspec(dllexport) void lib2_delete(lib2* p) { delete p; }
__declspec(dllexport) void lib2_func(lib2* p, char* c1, char* c2, double d) {
    p->func(c1,c2,d);
}
}
```

#### lib2.h

```
#ifdef LIB2_EXPORTS
#   define LIB2_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define LIB2_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class LIB2_API lib2
{
public:
    void func(char * c1, char * c2, double d);
};
```

#### lib2.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lib2.h"

void lib2::func(char * c1, char * c2, double d)
{
    printf("%s %s %f\n",c1,c2,d);
}
```

#### makefile

```
all: lib1.dll lib2.dll

lib1.dll: lib1.cpp lib2.dll
    cl /nologo /LD /W4 lib1.cpp -link lib2.lib

lib2.dll: lib2.cpp lib2.h
    cl /nologo /LD /W4 /D LIB2_EXPORTS lib2.cpp
```

#### test.py

```
#!python3
from ctypes import *

class lib2:

    lib1 = CDLL('lib1')
    # It's best to declare all arguments and types, so Python can typecheck.
    lib1.lib2_new.argtypes = []
    lib1.lib2_new.restype = c_void_p # Can use this for an opaque pointer.
    lib1.lib2_func.argtypes = [c_void_p,c_char_p,c_char_p,c_double]
    lib1.lib2_func.restype = None
    lib1.lib2_delete.argtypes = [c_void_p]
    lib1.lib2_delete.restype = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = self.lib1.lib2_new()

    def __del__(self):
        self.lib1.lib2_delete(self.obj)

    def func(self,c1,c2,d):
        self.lib1.lib2_func(self.obj,c1,c2,d)

o = lib2()
o.func(b'abc',b'123',1.2) # Note byte strings
```

#### Output

```
C:\temp>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 11.00.50727.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl /nologo /LD /W4 /D LIB2_EXPORTS lib2.cpp
lib2.cpp
   Creating library lib2.lib and object lib2.exp
        cl /nologo /LD /W4 lib1.cpp -link lib2.lib
lib1.cpp
   Creating library lib1.lib and object lib1.exp

C:\temp>test.py
abc 123 1.200000
```

### Alternatives

Since writing wrappers can be tedious, it is better to use something like `boost::Python`, `Cython`, or `SWIG`.  I'm most familiar with SWIG, so here's another example:

#### makefile

```
all: _lib2.pyd lib2.dll

PYTHON_ROOT = c:\python33

lib2_wrap.cxx: lib2.i
    @echo Generating wrapper...
    swig -c++ -python lib2.i

_lib2.pyd: lib2_wrap.cxx lib2.dll
    cl /nologo /EHsc /MD /LD /W4 /I$(PYTHON_ROOT)\include lib2_wrap.cxx -link lib2.lib /LIBPATH:$(PYTHON_ROOT)\libs /OUT:_lib2.pyd

lib2.dll: lib2.cpp lib2.h
    cl /nologo /LD /W4 /D LIB2_EXPORTS lib2.cpp
```

#### lib2.i

```
%module lib2

%begin %{
#pragma warning(disable:4127 4211 4706)
%}

%{
#include "lib2.h"
%}

%include <windows.i>
%include "lib2.h"
```

#### test.py

```
#!python3
import lib2
o = lib2.lib2()
o.func('abc','123',1.2) #Note SWIG encodes Unicode strings by default
```

#### Output

```
C:\temp>nmake /las
Generating wrapper...
lib2.cpp
   Creating library lib2.lib and object lib2.exp
lib2_wrap.cxx
   Creating library lib2_wrap.lib and object lib2_wrap.exp    

C:\temp>test
abc 123 1.200000
```

Comment: Thank u, @Mark Tolonen, I think your solution of "flattens" the C++ object is very smart! About the alternatives, I have tried to use SIP several days before using ctype. If ctype cannot meet my requirement, maybe I will switch to SIP or SWIG.

Comment: I tried to run your example, but it failed when I use 'nmake' for the makefile. I entered the msvs2008 "command prompt" and set the path to the files (using cd /d c:\temp), but I got linking errors. Does my msvs2008 have a problem, or do I need to add parameters such as libpaths?

Comment: "unsolved external symbol XXX". I changed a machine and it worked. Maybe I should re-install my msvs2008...

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  If the answer is useful to you, consider up voting and/or accepting the answer.

Comment: I re-installed my MSVS2008 and I successfully load my dll through SIP. I wish I could vote ur answer but I don't have enough reputation right now. Anyway, Thx to all your guys!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I can't reproduce this (Python 2.7.3, Windows 7 x64, Visual C++ Express 2008).

Lib2Dll.h:

```
#ifdef LIB2DLL_EXPORTS
#define LIB2DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define LIB2DLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"

class lib2
{
public:
  void LIB2DLL_API func_internal(char *s1, char *s2, double d);
};
```

Lib2Dll.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Lib2Dll.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void lib2::func_internal(char *s1, char *s2, double d)
{
    cout << "String 1: " << s1 << endl << "String 2: " << s2 << endl << "Double value: " << d << endl;
}
```

Lib1Dll.h:

```
#ifdef LIB1DLL_EXPORTS
#define LIB1DLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define LIB1DLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Lib2Dll.h"

extern "C" {
    void LIB1DLL_API func(char *s1, char *s2, double d);
}
```

Lib1Dll.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Lib1Dll.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

lib2 l;

void func(char *s1, char *s2, double d)
{
    cout << "Before" << endl; 
    l.func_internal(s1, s2, d);
    cout << "After" << endl; 
}
```

There are two projects in the VC++ 2008 solution, Lib2Dll (containing Lib2Dll.h and Lib2Dll.cpp) and Lib1Dll (containing Lib1Dll.h and Lib1Dll.cpp).  Lib1Dll depends on Lib2Dll.  Both libraries are set to use the cdecl calling convention.

I compiled the solution, and it generated Lib1Dll.dll and Lib2Dll.dll.  I then tried to use these libraries in Python:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from ctypes import CDLL, c_double
>>> l1 = CDLL("Lib1Dll")
>>> l1.func("ABC", "XYZ", c_double(3.2463))
Before
String 1: ABC
String 2: XYZ
Double value: 3.2463
After
1618402248
```

The number `1618402248` printed out at the bottom is a garbage value.  `ctypes` can't determine function return types, so it assumes they all return `int`.  In this case, our function is `void`, so it doesn't return anything.   The return value seen is whatever happened to occupy the memory location where `ctypes` thought a return value might be.  You can tell `ctypes` that this function's return type is `void` by setting `l1.func.restype = None`.

I'm not sure how you call the C++ method in Lib2Dll.dll directly.  I tried, and it almost worked, but I got an error, probably because I needed to pass an instance of a class somehow but didn't do so:

```
>>> l2 = CDLL("Lib2Dll")
>>> func_int = getattr(l2, "?func_internal@lib2@@QAEXPAD0N@Z")
>>> func_int("ABC", "XYZ", c_double(4.2612))
String 1: ABC
String 2: XYZ
Double value: 4.2612
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Procedure called with not enough arguments (16 bytes missing) or wrong calling convention
```

Comment: Thx very much for doing this test for me. I did not able to access to my code until today, since I was on a vacation. Sorry for replying so late. The "WindowsError" problem that occured when entering my func() in lib2.dll is caused by calling an old version of lib2.dll(dll hell), which I just found out today.  According to your program, it is also be ensured that the problem is not caused by parameter passing. I also removed all the parameters in func() to check the bug. Now I can enter the func() in lib2.dll, but I meet another "WindowsError"...

Comment: I will go on to check the new problem. thx for your help again!